# How to increment variable every time script is run in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby script that I want to increment a global variable every time it is run. Is this possible?

Comment: show your script

Comment: perhaps you're asking how to persist a variable so that it will be remembered between script invocations.  the usual approach is to read the value from a file (or database), increment it, and then write it back out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once Ruby closes, all the memory it contained is obviously lost, so the only way to make a value persist between runs is to store it externally. The obvious place is a file.

There are many different ways to output data, and different ways of storing, such as Ruby's Marshal format, XML, simple text, and JSON just to name a few common ways.

If all you need is a single simple number, then simple text will be the easiest to demonstrate.

To store the number:

```
$global = 10
File.open('global.txt', 'wb') { |file| file.write($global.to_s) }
```

To load it:

```
File.open('global.txt', 'rb') { |file|  $global = file.read.to_i }
```

This code is untested, just demonstrates the simplest way to go about this, not necessarily the best. I will leave it up to you to increment that variable and re-save it each run.

Reading could be simplified to not use a block, but I am maintaining similar style just for the example.

Comment: I think that in addition to what you proposed, the file holding the counter needs to be locked during processing, to avoid a race condition, if two instances of the script run in parallel.

Comment: Probably not a bad idea at all, but I have no clue what OP's intentions are, and am assuming by the nature of the question those types added complexities wouldn't be beneficial to understanding the basic question of reading/writing a persistent value. Most would agree that there are naturally better ways to do what I proposed, but I assume OP is learning the ropes, no need to make it more complex than it needs to be.